# Modify HTTP Method for Request in Browser

Tags: request, http-post, microsoft-edge

i am Learning Python and at the moment i am experimenting with the request Module.

**What i did so far:**
This is the API Documentation for the Endpoint i used:
https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/docs/#/default/post_v2_natural_exercise
And this is the associated Python Code:

```
EXERCISES_ENDPOINT = "https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/natural/exercise"
header = {
    "x-app-id": APP_ID,
    "x-app-key": API_KEY
}
body = {
    "query": "Ran 2 miles and walked  for 3Km."
}
response = requests.post(url=EXERCISES_ENDPOINT, headers=header, json=body)
```

The corresponding http Request URL should be:
https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/natural/exercise?Ran%202%20miles%20and%20walked%20%20for%203Km.

**My Problem is as follows:**

- In Python the code ist working perfectly fine and my response is as expected
- If i use Postman, this works fine too, because in both -Python and Postman - i can specify my Request as a POST Method
- But if i use the URL in my MS Edge Browser (and Chrome too) i get an Error: *Cannot GET /v2/natural/exercise*

The Header information are ok, because i told the Browser them per "ModHeader" Extension.
But why is my Browser doing a GET and not a POST and how can i change this with the developemant tools from MS Edge Browser.
Important for my learning is to know why the Browser do a GET??
Is the Browser only able to do GET in generel and the other Methods (POST, PUT, DELETE) are not possible in this way. But that makes no sense for me :)

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But why is my Browser doing a GET and not a POST

Presumably because you are trying the address into the address bar of the browser.

That is designed to make a GET request because there is nothing in the UI designed to collect any of the data needed to make another request type.

The usual way to make a POST request would be to provide a user interface for it in the form of an HTML `<form>`.

Comment: So in my case it is realy the best way to use Postman.. Thx a loat. I thought there is a way in the Browser Dev Tools to modify the request and send it again, this is not possible? In the section "Network" there is a way to see the Request an its details but not a way to modify it.

Comment: The Network tab is designed to let you see what requests you made so you can debug them, it isn't there as a generic REST client.